# How do I determine type of Haskell functions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm preparing for my exams but there is something I can't understand.

functions:

```
tw f x = f (f x)
f x y = (y, x)
```

I am able to determine the type of 'f' which is

```
f :: t1 -> t -> (t, t1)
```

but can't determine the type of 'tw'.

Supposed type of tw:

```
tw :: (t -> t) -> t -> t
```

thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be `tw x = f (f x)`? or even `tw f x = f (f x)`? Right now the `tw` function does not make much sense.

Comment: sorry i missed that. edited in this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us analyze the function `tw`:

```
tw f x = f (f x)
```

`tw` takes as parameters `f` and `x`. At the moment we dot not know much about these parameters, so we will give these as types `f :: a` and `x :: b`.

Now we see a function application with `f` the function and `x` the parameter. This thus means that `f` is a function that takes a value of type `b` (the type of `x`), and returns something. We thus specify that `f` has as type `f :: b -> c`, with `c` a new type variable we introduce. We thus know that `f x :: c`.

We furthermore see, that there is a function application with `f :: b -> c` the function, and `f x :: c` the parameter. Since the type of the parameter of `f` is `b`, and `f x` has as type `c`. We thus come to the conclusion, that `b` and `c` must be the same type.

This thus means that we derived as types:

```
x :: b
f :: b -> b
```

We can furthermore analyze the type of `tw f x` by determining the type of `f (f x)`. Since `f x` has type `f x :: b`, and `f` has type `f :: b -> b`, we know that `f (f x)` has type `f (f x) :: b`. So that means that the type for `tw` is:

```
tw :: (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

If we substitute `b` for `t`, then we obtain the expected type signature. But since `b` and `t` are just variables, that does not matter much.