# Haskell function that applies a list of functions to a list of inputs?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I need a Haskell function that takes a list of functions and a list of elements and applies the functions to the elements like this: the first function to the first element, the second function to the second element, etc. If any of the lists stop, I want the fuction to stop.
The difinition I came up with is this:

```
apply :: [(a -> b)] -> [a] -> [b]
```

I would like it to work something like this:

```
apply [(+1), (*3), (^2)] [1,2,3] == [2,6,9]
apply [even, odd] [1..] == [False, False]
```

Things I tried so far:

```
apply :: [(a -> b)] -> [a] -> [b]
apply [] _ = []
apply (f:fs) x = (f x) : (apply fs x)
```

Comment: `zipWith` is definitely a useful function to know about. As the above commenters say, both `zipWith ($)` and `zipWith id` will do what you want. They're the same because `($)` is actually the same as `id`, just restricted to functions (that's a little mind blowing at first, but it's true and I would encourage you to work out why) - for this reason I prefer using `($)` because it's more obvious you're talking about function application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented your recursion fails to recurse in the second argument, so the definition would be

```
apply (f:fs) (x:xs) = (f x) : (apply fs xs) 
apply _      _      = []
```

You can go point-free with

```
apply = zipWith ($) -- zipWith id works too as @Redu commented
```

Or even more interesting, you can go applicativelly-crazy with `ZipList`

```
import Control.Applicative
apply f x = getZipList $ ZipList f <*> ZipList x
```

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting  that in two comments are two totally valid answers:

```
applyAll' :: [b -> c] -> [b] -> [c]
applyAll = zipWith ($)
```

and

```
applyAll :: [a -> c] -> [a] -> [c]
applyAll' = zipWith id
```

It's also interesting that Haskell, due to [its way to pick types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285479/how-do-i-determine-type-of-haskell-functions) (type inference), changes a little bit its signature, obviously they are equivalent.
 `id` and `$` functions are equivalents when `id` is restricted to functions. (As Robin pointed out in his comment).